# How to create a row for items in a widget, with a next button?

Tags: android, android-widget

I am retrieving some items from html. Titles and dates...

What i want to do is put these in a widget.

But i want the widget to display a row for each item such as the title and date in a row and each item.

There is more than 1 item so it may all not fit into a widget. I know Listview's are not allowed on OS older then 3.0 So i was told i should display a button saying next..

SO how would i go about implementing this from  my discription above. Im familiar with how to create a widget just not to meet the criteria i need.

So how would i go about implementing this?

Such as how would i configure the button to change views to show the next items?